# GitHub Action for Google App Engine ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I had a GitHub action that was working perfectly until three months ago. However, since then, we have been unable to deploy anymore. I keep receiving a general error without any clear indication of what the issue might be.

We're getting this error :
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

My `main.yml` in GitHub:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  deploy_app_engine:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 80
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Update Google Cloud SDK
      run: |
        sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk
    - name: NodeJS Init
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '12'
        
    - name: Cache dependencies
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: ~/.npm
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-npm-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-npm-
        
    - name: Prepare NPM ENV
      run: |
        npm install
        npm install -g react-scripts
        npx browserslist@latest --update-db
        
    - name: Build Static Website
      run: npm run build
    - name: Initialize Google Cloud SDK
      uses: zxyle/publish-gae-action@master
      with:
        service_account_email: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_EMAIL }}
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
        project_id: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}
    
    - name: Publish app to Google App Engine
      run: |
        gcloud auth activate-service-account ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_EMAIL }} --key-file=client-secret.json
        gcloud config set project ${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}
        pwd
        gcloud -q app deploy app.yaml --promote
```

and this is the app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs12
service: default
handlers:
# Serve all static files with url ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/(.*\..+)$
# Catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
```

We're getting the error on the section of Publish app to Google App Engine, in the appengine I can see that it creates a new version but for some reason the issue not make this version to be live, and it does not look like the deployed have been done... how to investigate what's happen here?

It worked for about 2-2.5 years. We may have done something in mistake, but don't know what.

I tried to look on all changes that happen from the last day we could push, I tried to check all permission that relevant and do some changes with tutorials that nothing was working

When I use the 'deploy' command with the 'debug' option, I receive this additional data:

```
    ............................DEBUG: Operation [apps/***/operations/14779876-6eda-4628-9ea5-5ff567374e02] complete. Result: {
    "done": true,
    "error": {
        "code": 13,
        "message": "An internal error occurred."
    },
    "metadata": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1",
        "endTime": "2023-07-15T06:52:23.996Z",
        "insertTime": "2023-07-15T06:37:19.647Z",
        "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion",
        "target": "apps/***/services/default/versions/20230715t063706",
        "user": "***",
        "warning": [
            "Node.js 12 is no longer supported by the Node.js Foundation as of April 2022. We recommend you to upgrade to the latest version of Node.js runtime as soon as possible. For details on upgrading, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime."
        ]
    },
    "name": "apps/***/operations/14779876-6eda-4628-9ea5-5ff567374e02"
}
failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 987, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 127, in Run
    return deploy_util.RunDeploy(
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 692, in RunDeploy
    deployer.Deploy(
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 471, in Deploy
    self.api_client.DeployService(new_version.service, new_version.id,
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 230, in DeployService
    return operations_util.WaitForOperation(
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 307, in WaitForOperation
    completed_operation = waiter.WaitFor(
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 261, in WaitFor
    operation = PollUntilDone(
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 322, in PollUntilDone
    operation = retryer.RetryOnResult(
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 249, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 320, in _IsNotDone
    return not poller.IsDone(operation)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 182, in IsDone
    raise OperationError(requests.ExtractErrorMessage(
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.operations_util.OperationError: Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Anything in the GitHub Action log? Any clue in debug mode? (`gcloud -q app deploy app.yaml --promote --verbosity=debug`)

Comment: @VonC I update my post with the response of it

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/release-notes#April_11_2023 probably this.